# Does running an Android app on my phone through Android Studio slow it down?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, lag

I recently created my first game using Android Studio. I was wondering if running it on my phone (through Android Studio) will be any slower than running it as though it has been downloaded from the Play Store? I noticed that emulating my app on older Android phones is actually much faster than running it on my newer phone (the Samsung A5). My app also runs faster on older phones compared to newer phones when emulating it on a variety of devices. What might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, using ADB to debug and test your apps on a physical device doesn't necessarily slow it down. There is not much difference between installing the app via ADB and play store because in both cases the `.apk` file is installed onto the device. But you may experience some lag or delay with ADB because the entire log has to be captured by Android Studio and requires some amount of processing power from the device. It is like testing the app in developer mode. When you install an app from play store, it is the final build with the files cleaned and no need for log capturing and hence it can be faster.

Your app must be using some latest components which might only be available in the newer android versions whereas on the older ones they might be supported via the support libraries and hence the implementation is made simple on them due to lower processing power and RAM. Not all features and implementations are supported on the older Android versions.